# How to subset in RStudio properly?

Tags: r, subset

I have created the following data frame:

```r
age <- c(21,35,829,2)
sex <- c("m","f","m","c")
height <- c(181,173,171,166)
weight <- c(69,58,75,60)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,sex,height,weight), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat$age <- as.numeric(age)
dat
```

I want to choose now only the rows of students which are older than 20 or younger than 80.

Why does this work : `dat[dat$age<20| dat$age>80,]   ;   subset(dat, age < 20 | age > 80)`

But this does not: `dat[dat$age>20| dat$age<80,]   ; subset(dat, age > 20 | age < 80)`

I can subset the rows who are NOT younger than 80 or older than 20, but not those who are actually in this interval.

What is the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `dat[dat$age %in% 20:80,]`

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect. I made edits for make it correct.

Comment: This may be a logic problem: *"older than 20 or younger than 80"* resolves to everybody, always, perfectly. There is no (real) number that is not one of those two inequality. (829 is older than 20, 2 is younger than 80.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your condition allows basically every possible age. Think about it, your conditions are independent (because you are using the `|` operator), so every row, that fits in one of your conditions, are selected by your filter. Every age that is defined in your data.frame now, are higher than 20, OR if not, they certainly are lower than 80.

If you want to select every row, that is in between age 20 and 80, you would change the logic operator. To make these conditions dependent, like this:

```
dat[dat$age>20 & dat$age<80,]
subset(dat, age > 20 & age < 80)
```

**Resulting this:**

```
  age sex height weight
1  21   m    181     69
2  35   f    173     58
```

Now, if you want to select all the rows, that are outside of this interval, you could negate this logic condition with the `!` operator, like was suggested by @r2evans in the comment section. It would be something like this:

```
dat[!(dat$age > 20 & dat$age < 80),]
subset(dat, !(age > 20 & age < 80))
```

**Resulting this:**

```
  age sex height weight
3 829   m    171     75
4   2   c    166     60
```

Comment: In case orienting the logic may be a point of confusing (often I need to just write things out verbosely to get all pieces together/correct)... the other rows are `subset(dat, !(age > 20 & age < 80))`.

Comment: But you think my answer confusing? I dont know if is that what you pointing out here.

Comment: No I don't think your answer is confusing ... I think logic can be confusing, indicated by the statement *"older than 20 or younger than 80"*. It can be confusing in general, and I think your answer explains that well. The point of my comment was an add-on, to try to help cement (in the OP's view) what logic provides what output.

Comment: Oh yeah! You wright, I got confused by this statement too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use dplyr filter?

```
library(dplyr)

df_age <- dat %>%
  dplyr::filter(age > 20
                , age < 80)
```